# Sinonjs not stubbing class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon

I want to stub a method that I call like this:

```
let context = new AuthenticationContext(authAuthorityUrl, true)
context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword()
```

I defined my stub method like this:

```
let stub = sandbox.stub(AuthenticationContext.prototype,'acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword').callsFake(fkFn)
```

But when I run the code, I get an error thrown from the real acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword, which I don't want to call

Comment: Try using `context` instead of AuthenticationContext

Answer (score 0):

It should work. E.g.

`AuthenticationContext.ts`:

```js
export class AuthenticationContext {
  constructor(private url: string, private flag: boolean) {}
  public acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword() {
    console.log('real implementation');
  }
}
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { AuthenticationContext } from './AuthenticationContext';

export function main() {
  const authAuthorityUrl = 'localhost';
  let context = new AuthenticationContext(authAuthorityUrl, true);
  context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword();
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { AuthenticationContext } from './AuthenticationContext';

describe('62797402', () => {
  let sandbox;
  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const fkFn = () => console.log('fake implementation');
    let stub = sandbox.stub(AuthenticationContext.prototype, 'acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword').callsFake(fkFn);
    main();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  62797402
fake implementation
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (27ms)

--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                 |   88.89 |      100 |   66.67 |    87.5 |                   
 AuthenticationContext.ts |      75 |      100 |      50 |   66.67 | 4                 
 index.ts                 |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```